# How to detect whether a NSString contains one capital letter or not

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a textField where I am entering password.
Can anyone please tell me how can I check the text that I am entering contains one capital letter or not? 
I have gone through web but failed to get what exactly I am wanting. Thanks in advance.

This is where I want to add the checkins.

```
if([self.txtfldPw.text isEqualToString:@""] && [self.txtfldPw.text.length = ] && [self.txtfldEmail.text = ]) {
    UIAlertView *pwAlrt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Password Must Be Of Six Characters And One Of The Letters Should Be Caps" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [pwAlrt show];
    [self.btnLogin setEnabled:YES];
}
```

Comment: at lease one or exact one

Comment: you can simply use regular expressions

Comment: at least one capital letter.

Comment: can you give all requirement for password.. ie min-max length and all so I can share regular expression with you

Comment: I want to have two checkins- 1. Minimum 6 characters, 2. At least one of them should be caps.

Comment: ^.*(?=.{6,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$  use this regular expression to validate string.... this will also check minimum one lowercase letter

Comment: @nirmal check once my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

simply use below code to validate your password.

Add method

```
- (BOOL)isValidPassword:(NSString*)password
{
    NSRegularExpression* regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"^.*(?=.{6,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$" options:0 error:nil];
    return [regex numberOfMatchesInString:password options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [password length])] > 0;
}
```

use this code for checking condition.

```
if(![self isValidPassword:[password stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]]) {
    UIAlertView *pwAlrt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Password Must Be Of Six Characters And One Of The Letters Should Be Caps" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [pwAlrt show];
    [self.btnLogin setEnabled:YES];
}
```

Comment: Dude! What is this "whitespaceCharacterSet"? An error is coming with this. It's showing that use of undeclared identifier "whitespaceCharacterSet". :(

Comment: this is for removing leading and trailing whitespace character for minimum length requirement

Answer (score 13):

Here use your string from `UITextField` or any other source to find it contains any `uppercase` or not.

```
NSString *str = @"Apple";
//get all uppercase character set
NSCharacterSet *cset = [NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet];
//Find range for uppercase letters
NSRange range = [str rangeOfCharacterFromSet:cset];
//check it conatins or not
if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"not any capital");
} else {
    NSLog(@"has one capital");
}
```

**EDIT** According to your requirement : 1. Minimum 6 characters. 2. At least one of them should be caps. so `Nirmal Choudhari`'s regex can used with following method for checking its valid or not

```
- (BOOL)containsValidPassword:(NSString*)strText
{
  NSString* const pattern = @"^.*(?=.{6,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$";
  NSRegularExpression* regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:nil];
  NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [strText length]);
  return [regex numberOfMatchesInString:strText options:0 range:range] > 0;
}
```

Usage :

```
NSString *str = @"appLe";
BOOL isValid = [self containsValidPassword:str];
if (isValid) {
    NSLog(@"valid");
} else {
    NSLog(@"not valid");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this to determine wether there is one ore more uppercase letters in the string:

```
 NSString *string = @"Test";
NSString *lowercaseString = [string lowercaseString];

BOOL containsUppercaseLetter = ![string isEqualToString:lowercaseString];
```

Comment: +ONE : *I would say this is best* ***ugly*** *way to check...*

Comment: best way for this question :D

Answer (score 2):

Try This out. It Will Check for two password validation.
1. Password must contain one capital and one small alphabet.
2. No special character is allowed.

```
- (BOOL)isPasswordValid:(NSString *)password
{
    NSCharacterSet * characterSet = [NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] ;
    NSRange range = [password rangeOfCharacterFromSet:characterSet] ;
    if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
        return NO ;
    }
    characterSet = [NSCharacterSet lowercaseLetterCharacterSet] ;
    range = [password rangeOfCharacterFromSet:characterSet] ;
    if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
        return NO ;
    }

    characterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"] ;
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [password length]; ++i) {
        unichar uchar = [password characterAtIndex:i] ;
        if (![characterSet characterIsMember:uchar]) {
            return NO ;
        }
    }
    return YES ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)passwordvarify:(NSString*)password // pass your password here it will return true if it contains one uppercase letter else false just call this method and evaluate your password on the basis of true and false
{

    int count=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < [password length]; i++) {
        BOOL isUppercase = [[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[password characterAtIndex:i]];
        if (isUppercase == YES)
        {
            count++;
            break;

        }
    }
    if(count == 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"password have one uppercase letter");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"password do not have uppercase letter");
        return false;

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
NSString *s = @"This is a string";  
int count=0;  
BOOL isUppercase;
for (i = 0; i < [s length]; i++) {
    isUppercase= [[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[s characterAtIndex:i]];
   if (isUppercase)
      break;
}

isUppercase?NSLog("String contain uppercase letter"):NSLog("String does not contain uppercase letter")
```

Comment: I want to check this in if statement. How can I do this?